# hitTest with objects from two arrays

Tags: flash, actionscript-3

Basically what I'm looking to do is hitTest bullets inside an array (spawn via addChild -> pushed into an array) with another array containing ships (spawn via addChild -> pushed into an array as well).

At the moment I have:

```
function moveEnemyLarge():void{
    var target2:EnemyLarge;

    for(var i2:int=0;i2<enemyShipArray.length;i2++){
        // Move each ship in the array down.
        target2 = EnemyLarge(enemyShipArray[i2]);
        target2.y += 0.5;

        // Hit Test
        if(target2.hitTestObject(PLACEHOLDER)){
            trace("SHIP HIT BULLET");
            removeChild(target2);
            enemyShipArray.splice(i2,1);
            i2--;
        }

        // Remove when off-stage.
        if(target2.y > 700){
            removeChild(target2);
            enemyShipArray.splice(i2,1);
            i2--;
        }
    }
}
```

.. and a near identical function for the bullets (using variables: i, target).
What is the easiest way for me to hitTest the objects within my bullet array with the objects in my ship array. Putting "target" in the PLACEHOLDER slot doesn't work, and from what I've seen some people will shove the one for() inside of the other.

Let me know if you need any further code or explanations on my part - I'm just learning the ropes of AS3 and have yet to learn a bunch techniques!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The obvious solution will be 2 loops.

```
for (var i:int = 0; i < ships.length; i++) {
  var target:EnemyLarge = ships[i];
  target.y += .5;
  for (var j:int = 0; j < bullets.length; j++) {
    var bullet:Bullet = bullets[j];
    if (target.hitTestObject(bullet)) {
      ships.splice(i,1); i--;
      removeChild(target);
    }
  }
}
```

This one is OK for simple learning projects but it has several flaws:

1. Never (I said NEVER) modify the collection you are iterating. You will have hours of debugging later trying to understand what's going on.
2. If bullets or ships are very fast a bullet can move through ship in one frame. In this case you might want to test not just a bullet but a line from bullet's last position to current position.
3. You will get issues if you have lots of bullets and ships. In this case you will need some data structure to query bullets near ships faster than linear search.

Answer (score 0):

In your setup you have to resort to a loop inside a loop in order to check each bullet against each ship (or vise-versa). The inner loop will look like this:

```
for(var bullet:Bullet in bullets) {
 if(target2.hitTestObject(bullet)){
  trace("SHIP HIT BULLET");
  bullet.parent.removeChild(bullet); // remove the bullet
  removeChild(target2);
  enemyShipArray.splice(i2,1);
  i2--;
 }
}
```

There's a couple ways to alternatively work around this.

- grid system in which each cell only checks for collisions for its children
- partitioning the game space into Y spaces, if there is a collision on that plain, then check for X axis collision
- pixel lookup in which the bullet reads some color coded information on which ship it has hit
- and some others that I can't think of right now